# Class Carbon\Carbon not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php, php-carbon

I recently added a package to my Laravel 4 site and now anything that uses Eloquent (or at least Eloquent with any reference to date/time) is showing a 500 error that states:

```
Class 'Carbon\Carbon' Not Found.
```

I tried running

```
composer install
composer update
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not saying this is work for you, but those are steps that usually fix Laravel, when the problem is not on your source code, of course:

```
cd /your/application/dir

rm bootstrap/compiled.php

rm -rf vendor

composer install --no-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I realized that what it needed was nesbot/carbon, I attempted to install using composer and it failed due to dependency issues. I uploaded it from my project folder and now everything works again... ugh

Answer (score 74):

Yes, it can work as @oli-folkerd 's answer. However, as seen in Laracasts ([Laravel 5 Fundamentals series Video 10 "forms" min 16:55](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/10)), almost in top of your ControllerClass php file, just add the following (or import the class if your php editor allows you do so):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Now you can simply use `Carbon`

```
$input['published_at'] = Carbon::now();
```

without having to add `Carbon\`

Comment: it's inserting the date time but the time is not the local time. how can I insert local date-time??

Answer (score 57):

you need to add the line:

```
'Carbon' => 'Carbon\Carbon',
```

to the bottom of the `'aliases'` array in app/config/app.php this will make the carbon library available everywhere in laravel.

Answer (score 21):

You this class in controller of Laravel.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

then you simply define the carbon command for print the current date

```
$date = Carbon::now();
```

Answer (score 15):

For all updated version you just need to

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

and for the global use, you can add this in app.php

`'Carbon' => 'Carbon\Carbon'`,

Comment: None of the answers worked for me , but this one worked!

Answer (score 10):

For Laravel 8.x Please add

```
'Carbon' => Illuminate\Support\Carbon::class,
```

in your app/config/app.php

under aliases

or if you only want to use it in your controller

then please add

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
```

Comment: It just bothers me why it is not already on app.php this is one of the very most common class

Answer (score 8):

My problem solved by just requiring nesbot/carbon just do this:

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

Comment: This solution worked for, am just wondering why `composer update` didn't resolve it initially

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem once when I updated a project from `gitlab`. The below command worked for me.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times specifying `prefer-dist` prefixed by “--” (aka “bare double dash”) at the end or suffixing at the end of `create-project` also matters while installing...

The below command was working fine in **laravel 5.5** without getting an error

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog  "5.5.*" --prefer-dist
```

But when I was about to begin installing **Laravel 5.6** with this below command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist
```

I used to get

> Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : Class 'Carbon\Carbon' not found

After referring to the official [Installation Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#installation)

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

After executing the above command there were no exceptions raised, therefore installation succeeded, thereby generating a base64 hash key

Answer (score 0):

In  your view file,try to access to the class like this :

```
{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the problem I had, I solved it by changing the date from:

`date: '{{\Carbon::today->format('Y-m-d') }}'`

to

`date: '{{\Carbon\Carbon::today()->format("Y-m-d") }}'`

Comment: While this technically works, if you frequently use Carbon from your blade views then it might be better to make Carbon a globally available alias that your blade views can access by following this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67438679