# Class 'Carbon\Laravel\ServiceProvider' not found when composer update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I try composer update in my Laravel project I have this error on the terminal

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

Class 'Carbon\Laravel\ServiceProvider' not found
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21366686/11608095

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class Carbon\Carbon not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366660/class-carbon-carbon-not-found)

Comment: Don't work for me :(

Comment: Check all the answers.

Comment: try this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366660/class-carbon-carbon-not-found>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try deleting the cache in laravel project folder, you navigate to bootstrap folder, then delete items in cache.

Answer (score 0):

run this command on your project. all require class will be download

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok I solved the problem.

First delete the bootstrap/cache/packages.php then

```
rm -rf vendor

composer install --no-dev
```