# Laravel: How to change Time Stamps Format in Excel Export?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, timestamp, maatwebsite-excel

I am generating a Excel Export, I want to change the timestamps format in excel file from 2020-07-29 13:56:09 to just `DD:MM:YYYY`.
How can I change my Export Class to Format the timestamp Column in my Excel File, BTW Date is in 'E' column in Excel file.
My Export Class:

```
use App\outbound_detail;
use App\outbound_temp;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class ReleaseExportView implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{
    protected $reference;

    function __construct($reference)
    {
        $this->reference = $reference;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return outbound_detail::where('reference', $this->reference)->get([
            'reference', 'sku_parent', 'sku_child', 'cases', 'updated_at'
        ]);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Reference',
            'SKU Parent',
            'SKU Child',
            'Cases Released',
            'Date Created'
        ];
    }
    // ...

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                $cellRange = 'A1:W1'; // All headers
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(14);
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `Reference` Model, add this :

```
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('d:m:Y');
}
```

Comment: Class Carbon\Carbon not found

Comment: You need to [install and import the namespace](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). Run `composer require nesbot/carbon`, and then import it at the top of your controller with `use Carbon\Carbon;`

Comment: Change to `\Carbon\Carbon`

Comment: Or try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51203217/4575350

Answer (score 0):

You can use it's [column formatting](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html).
Try this:

```
// ...
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;

class ReleaseExportView implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents, WithColumnFormatting
{
    // ...

    public function map($reference): array
    {
        return [
            $reference->reference,
            $reference->sku_parent,
            $reference->sku_child,
            $reference->cases,
            Date::dateTimeToExcel($reference->updated_at)
        ];
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'E' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Class 'App\Exports\NumberFormat' not found, Which class to import?

Comment: @KundanNasir My bad. It's `use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat`

Comment: @KundanNasir That's weird, the sample code was from a working application. Looks like I forgot to add the `use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;` as well. Did you add the `WithColumnFormatting` into the class implements?  If that didn't work either, can you try `$reference->updated->format('d:m:Y')` as last resort.

Comment: tried everything you said, date format still is the same as db time stamps